# Declaring Java object array

Tags: java

I have the following code, that i have revised multiple times:

```
public class double3 {
    public double x=0;
    public double y=0;
    public double z=0;
    public double3(double a, double b, double c){
        this.x=a;
        this.y=b;
        this.z=c;
    }
}


double3[] samples = new double3[4];//syntax error on token ";", { expected after this token
samples[0]=new double3(1,2,3);
```

What is happening here and what is eclipse trying to say to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statements

```
double3[] samples = new double3[4];
samples[0] = new double3(1,2,3);
```

should be in a code block such as a method, constructor or instance initializer

Comment: Right, because Java is unlike scripting languages such as Javascript that allow for arbitrary execution of code outside of methods.  A main method is needed to kickstart the process.

Comment: Yes! Dumb error of me. It was actually inside a bigger and lengthy class, and my previous C experience doesn't warn me about this things. Thank you! (I will accept when allowed to)

Comment: Note that Java classes start with an uppercase letter, e.g. `Double3` - read more [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367)

Comment: Thank you for the reference, Reimus.  But one thing that is kind of strange for me is the error message. Why should it expect "{" after the ";" token?

Comment: Yes, but why does it expects it *after* the semicolon? Shouldn't it be before? I know it means that it expects it after the last correctly parsed token, but this error message is kind of confusing

Comment: Actually its the statement: `samples[0] = ...`. It expects to find it in a code block so its expecting the brace `{`

Comment: It doesn't expect it after the semicolon, it expects a brace *before* the semicolon but gets the semicolon first and chokes.

Comment: Oh, it makes more sense now. Thanks!